# possible optimization in getting Minimum value indices from upper 2-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, optimization

Hi Can anyone help me in optimizing the function of getting minimum value from a two-dimensional array, I have to see only upper or lower triangular matrix. I have a big array of size 30000 *30000 and I have to find the indices of minimum value. and I have also a masked array that I used to ignore certian rows and columuns

```
def get_min_distance(self,data,min_ind2):
    ind1=0
    ind2=0
    return_ind1=0
    return_ind2=0
    min_val=1000000
    if min_ind2!=-1:
        self.maskedArray[min_ind2]=1
    for x in range(len(data)-1):
        j=x+1
        ind1=x
        if self.maskedArray[x]==1:
            pass
        else:
            min_max_array=ma.masked_array((data[x]),self.maskedArray
            ind2=int(np.argmin(min_max_array[j:]))+j
            if self.maskedArray[ind2]==1:
                pass
            else:
                if min_val>data[ind1,ind2]:
                    min_val=data[ind1,ind2]
                    return_ind1=ind1
                    return_ind2=ind2
                else:
                    pass
    return return_ind1,return_ind2,min_val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.triu(data, k=1)` to generate an upper-triangular matrix from `data`. Alternatively, you can use `np.tril(np.full(data.shape, val))` to generate a lower tridiagonal matrix filled with `val`. Moreover, you can filter your matrix with `data[rowMask, :][:, colMask]` if `rowMask` and `colMask` are both Boolean arrays. Finally, `np.argmin` takes an axis to choose to iterate over all lines or columns of a given matrix. If not specified, it returns the flatten index of the minimum element.

You can mix them together to get what you want. Here is an example:

```py
min_val = 1000000 # Better to set it to np.inf if the datatype if float32/float64

# Discard the lower-part of the matrix
triuData = np.triu(data, k=1) + np.tril(np.full(data.shape, min_val))

# Filter the lines and the columns
filteredData = triuData[rowMask, :][:, rowMask]

# Find the location of the minimum element in the filtered matrix
flattenMinId = np.argmin(filteredData)
return_ind1 = flattenMinId // filteredData.shape[1]
return_ind2 = flattenMinId % filteredData.shape[1]

# Reconstruct the index from the original data matrix
return_ind1 = np.where(np.cumsum(rowMask) == return_ind1)[0][0]
return_ind1 = np.where(np.cumsum(colMask) == return_ind2)[0][0]
```

This code may not be very efficient due to temporary matrices. Alternatively, You can use Numba's `@njit` to get better performance.